# Question on converting decimal to binary to hex

Tags: binary, decimal, hex

I'm a little confused here:

I'm trying to reverse engineer the ASCII value 65. In the book I am reading it says:

```
Decimal: 65
Hex:  41
Octal: 101
```

But 65 in its binary representation is:

```
0010 0001
```

And `0010` in hex is 2, while `0001` is 1, which indicates that the hex value "should" be: 21.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

65 dec in bin is 0100 0001.

Comment: This right here is the answer. 0010 0001 is actually 33, not 65.

Comment: @John: Yeah, but mrblah is also believes that the first four digits represent the first digits in the hex number.

Comment: um, thats how you do bin to hex (at least in an ad hoc way) - its easy cos hex is a power of 2 so you have a fixed number of bits for each hex char

Comment: assuming your binary is padded to nibble boundaries of course, which is true in this case

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, jk. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 4):

you have the binary wrong - it should be 0100 0001 - your bin to hex is fine

incidentally bin->oct->dec->hex is one of the things calc.exe is actually really useful for

Comment: Especially in calc's Win7 incarnation.

Answer (score 1):

65 in decimal is:

```
 0100 0001
```

You're off by a digit in the first nibble.